# unable to install drawnow package

Tags: python, raspberry-pi-os

when I try to install the drawnow package, there are some mistakes.

I type

```py
sudo pip install drawnow
```

it returns

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo pip install drawnow
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://www.piwheels.org/simple
Collecting drawnow
  Using cached https://www.piwheels.org/simple/drawnow/drawnow-0.72.5-py3-none-any.whl (4.3 kB)
Collecting matplotlib>=1.5
  Using cached matplotlib-3.3.4.tar.gz (37.9 MB)
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /usr/local/bin/python3.6 -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-so6oyd3t/matplotlib_f0fbcfb46b7744ccaa8d8a56760c62db/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-so6oyd3t/matplotlib_f0fbcfb46b7744ccaa8d8a56760c62db/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-l50v6quo
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-so6oyd3t/matplotlib_f0fbcfb46b7744ccaa8d8a56760c62db/
    Complete output (87 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 157, in save_modules
        yield saved
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 198, in setup_context
        yield
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 248, in run_setup
        DirectorySandbox(setup_dir).run(runner)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 278, in run
        return func()
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 246, in runner
        _execfile(setup_script, ns)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 47, in _execfile
        exec(code, globals, locals)
      File "/tmp/easy_install-pc0vv8gr/numpy-1.20.1/setup.py", line 30, in <module>
        from setuptools import setup, find_packages, Extension
    RuntimeError: Python version >= 3.7 required.
    
    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
    
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-install-so6oyd3t/matplotlib_f0fbcfb46b7744ccaa8d8a56760c62db/setup.py", line 312, in <module>
        cmdclass=cmdclass,
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/distutils/core.py", line 108, in setup
        _setup_distribution = dist = klass(attrs)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 315, in __init__
        self.fetch_build_eggs(attrs['setup_requires'])
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 361, in fetch_build_eggs
        replace_conflicting=True,
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 850, in resolve
        dist = best[req.key] = env.best_match(req, ws, installer)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1122, in best_match
        return self.obtain(req, installer)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1134, in obtain
        return installer(requirement)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 429, in fetch_build_egg
        return cmd.easy_install(req)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 665, in easy_install
        return self.install_item(spec, dist.location, tmpdir, deps)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 695, in install_item
        dists = self.install_eggs(spec, download, tmpdir)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 876, in install_eggs
        return self.build_and_install(setup_script, setup_base)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1115, in build_and_install
        self.run_setup(setup_script, setup_base, args)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1101, in run_setup
        run_setup(setup_script, args)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 251, in run_setup
        raise
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/contextlib.py", line 100, in __exit__
        self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 198, in setup_context
        yield
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/contextlib.py", line 100, in __exit__
        self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 169, in save_modules
        saved_exc.resume()
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 144, in resume
        six.reraise(type, exc, self._tb)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/_vendor/six.py", line 685, in reraise
        raise value.with_traceback(tb)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 157, in save_modules
        yield saved
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 198, in setup_context
        yield
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 248, in run_setup
        DirectorySandbox(setup_dir).run(runner)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 278, in run
        return func()
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 246, in runner
        _execfile(setup_script, ns)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 47, in _execfile
        exec(code, globals, locals)
      File "/tmp/easy_install-pc0vv8gr/numpy-1.20.1/setup.py", line 30, in <module>
        from setuptools import setup, find_packages, Extension
    RuntimeError: Python version >= 3.7 required.
    
    Edit setup.cfg to change the build options; suppress output with --quiet.
    
    BUILDING MATPLOTLIB
      matplotlib: yes [3.3.4]
          python: yes [3.6.1 (default, Mar  4 2021, 20:37:42)  [GCC 8.3.0]]
        platform: yes [linux]
     sample_data: yes [installing]
           tests: no  [skipping due to configuration]
          macosx: no  [Mac OS-X only]
```

Comment: I do not understand the question.  What are you trying to do? E.g. what command are you running?  What is the result?  What did you expect to happen?  EDIT this information into your question.

Comment: I failed to install the drawnow package and there is a contradiction between whereis python and python --version. I guess the python environment causes the failure.

Comment: Do not post illegible pictures post text.

Comment: "uninstalled the python2.7" i.e. you broke the OS. Start from scratch and **DON'T DELETE** things.

Comment: Thank you for the advice.I have edited the question and put the code.

Comment: thanks,I will reinstall the raspberry OS

Comment: Today I reinstall the raspberry OS and install the python3 without any deletion. At this time. the process goes well. Thanks for your suggestion, It is really instructive to a freshman like me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank Milliways for his help.

As he said, the mistake happened as I uninstalled the python2 from my raspberry pi OS, which is a part of the operation system.

I reinstall the raspberry pi OS, and install python3

```
pip install python3
```

delete the link before

```
sudo rm /usr/bin/python
```

build up a new link to the python3 I have just installed

```
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/python3.7 /usr/bin/python
```

tips: the 3.7 in the code could be changed. The python you installed decides the number you code (such as 3.5 or 3.6)

coding `python`, you will see the default python in the raspberry pi.

then

```
sudo pip3 install drawnow
```

Using the method above, I successfully install the drawnow package on raspberry pi.

Comment: Please make sure to accept your answers so that the question is marked as complete.